# Changing Timezone in XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have some Java code that converts and XML to CSV using XSL. The time being recorded from XML is in GMT. I need to switch it to CST/CDT. The XSL looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java" >
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Tag4">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@id,',',@score,',',@average,',',/Tag1/@createddate,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML here looks like this:

```
<Tag1 doc="something" createddate="2016-02-12T18:48:01Z">
  <Tag2 xattribute="01">
    <Tag3 valueat="02">
      <Tag4 id="01" score="20" average="30"></Tag4>
      <Tag4 id="02" score="40" average="60"></Tag4>
    </Tag3>
  </Tag2>
</Tag1>
```

I tried using Current Time using Java but as expected the value differs from the XML value. XML is streaming continuously but there is a slight gap if I use current time using this in XSL:

```
java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z'),java:java.util.Date.new())
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try using `ZonedDateTime` class of Java 8.

Comment: I can only use Java 7. Can I use a function to do the conversion in XSL itself?

Comment: Since XSLT 2.0 introduces a lot of support for date/time manipulation including timezones, you really need to specify XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 for a question like this. In 2.0, it's easily done using the adjust-dateTime-to-timezone() function.

Comment: You won't be able to do this in XSLT (2.0) alone, because it doesn't know when DST starts/ends.